# Disable Jquery submit button once submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to disable the submit button once the form has been submitted. That means the submit button should not be clickable after the user click submit. That means I want the submit button to remain disable even after refresh

```
; (function ($) {

    $.fn.tpFormDialogCustom = function (method) {

        var self = this;

        var dialogButtons = [
          {
              text: "Submit and Email",
              id: "tpFormDialog_btnSubmit",
              click: submitandmailTpFormDialog
          },


function submitandmailTpFormDialog() {
  if(CheckValidate()) {
    commonDialogs.showError(ExampleMessages.JournalError);
  } else {
    commonDialogs.showConfirm(ExampleMessages.ConfirmEmail, function() {
      try {
        commonDialogs.showProgress(ExampleMessages.SubmitAndEmail);
        var o = getOptions();
        var form = $(o.form);
        form.ajaxSubmit({
          success: handleEmailResponse,
          beforeSerialize: function($form, options) {
            if(!$("#SubmitBtn", $form).length) {
              $('select.required', $form).prop('disabled', false);
              $form.append("<input id='SubmitBtn' type='hidden' name='From' value='Submit' />");
            }
          }
        });
      } catch(e) {
        commonDialogs.showError();
      }
    });
  }
}


function handleEmailResponse(data) {
            $('#tpFormDialog_btnSubmit').prop("disabled", true);
            commonDialogs.hideProgress();
            var o = getOptions();
            if (data.IsSuccess) {
                commonDialogs.showAck(ExampleMessages.ConfirmSendEmail);
                closeTpFormDialog();
                o.table.refresh();
            } else {
                var errors = data.ResponseModel;
                if (typeof (errors) === 'string') {
                    commonDialogs.showError(errors);
                } else {
                    helpForValidation.showErrors(errors);
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: I usually hide my submit buttons with display none on click and replace them with a 'thank you for contacting us' type message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery disable button (popup dialog)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39197502/jquery-disable-button-popup-dialog)

Answer (score 3):

You can disable your submit button by adding disable property to submit button.

```
$('input:submit').click(function(){
    console.log("Form is submiting.....");
    $('input:submit').attr("disabled", true);
});
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/Prakash_Thete/6qqgszs4/

Answer (score 2):

You should do it on `ajax` `success` so in case of `error` the user can re submit the form.
In your case it would be inside the `handleEmailResponse` function.

```
function handleMailResponse(){
    $('#btnSubmitId').prop("disabled", true);

    /* the rest of your code */
}
```

Comment: Hi, i added it to the handlemailresponse but it doesn't seems to work. The updated answer is at the top.

Comment: $('tpFormDialog_btnSubmit').prop("disabled", true); should be $('#tpFormDialog_btnSubmit').prop("disabled", true); with a hash # if it is declared as id <button id="tpFormDialog_btnSubmit"></button>

Comment: added #. still not working. I want the submit button to remain disable after refresh.

Comment: if the button is disabled after refresh how user will be able to delete an item ?? that makes no sense